# Displaying Data on Autocomplete in Asp.Net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I have writtten code for auto complete for a textbox. It works fine. My intention is to populate data in a div below the textbox on typing data just like google search. Is there any option to do that.

I have a controller which returns results to view.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how have you implemented the autocomplete?

Comment: I would recommend using JqueryUI auto-complete with ajax calls

Comment: I implemented Jquery UI auto-complete finally. Thanks It Worked